# Integral of Product of Besselfunction and Exponential

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

I am trying to find a closed form solution for the following integral:
$$\phi(t) = \int_0^\infty J_0(r\cdot t) \; e^{-\frac{1}{2}(r^2-1)^2} r \; dr $$
The function $J_0$ denotes the Bessel function of the first kind (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html).
I tried to solve it with Mathematica but that failed.

Question: Is there a way to solve this integral and to find a better representation for $\phi(t)$?

Comment: Do you mean (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function)

$J_0(rt) =  \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} cos(-rtsin(\beta)) d \beta$ ?

Comment: Yeah, I guess there are multiple definitions of the Bessel function. This is one of them. The link to wolfram.com (in my question) lists a few more.

Comment: I read the entire article here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function and saw no property that can help here

Comment: Maybe you need some kind of transformation and back

Comment: Or solve it in C and check whther $\phi (z)$ is real ... just an idea

Comment: Do you have access to research gate? https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220257438_Integrating_products_of_Bessel_functions_with_an_additional_exponential_or_rational_factor

Comment: Managed to obtain an Infinite Series Answer from Mathematica: $$\phi(t)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left( \frac{(-1)^n 2^{-\frac{3}{2} (n+1)} t^{2 n} \left(\, _1F_1\left(-\frac{n}{2};\frac{1}{2};-\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)+\sqrt{2} \, _1F_1\left(\frac{1-n}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{2}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)\right)}{(n!)^2}\right)$$. Its intriguing that this function in $t$ seems like a highly damped version of a Bessel Function, $J_0$, but cannot find a way of simplifing further.